# Reference JS file in JS file

Tags: javascript

I have a Js function that I would like to:

1. Reference another js file
2. Pull a function out.

I would like to do this JS side and not reference on the actual page as I need this process to happen dynamically.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Pulling a specific function and nothing else from another JS file?  I don't see that being possible unless you want to load it into a server side language like PHP and parse it... otherwise you will just need to pull the entire script file. (Assuming its on the same domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with the browser, jQuery has an helper function for it, [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Comment: Appending a script tag to the head element will load it in asynchronously, there's no need for ajax.

Answer (score 2):

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    s = document.createElement('script');

s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.onload = function () { document.getElementById('hello').innerText = h.innerText; };
s.src = 'http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js';
h.appendChild(s);
```

---

see:  http://jsbin.com/uhoger

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of is to dynamically insert a new script tag into the page targeting your desired script from your initial javascript. Just have your initial script insert the new `<script>` tag on load, or upon request and then test for availability.